# Web scrapping can't grab the source of an image

Tags: python, web-scraping

```
import requests
import bs4
res2 = requests.get("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)")
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res2.text,'lxml')
soup.select(".image")
computer = soup.select(".image")[0]
computer['class']
computer ['src']
```

When I run computer['class] I get back the class name
``But when I run computer['src'] I get the following error

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [19], in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 computer['src']

File C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\bs4\element.py:1519, in Tag.**getitem**(self, key)
1516 def **getitem**(self, key):
1517     """tag[key] returns the value of the 'key' attribute for the Tag,
1518     and throws an exception if it's not there."""
-> 1519     return self.attrs[key]

KeyError: 'src'

Comment: I think you need the href

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is because the key "src" is not found in the "attrs" dictionary of the element. To access the source URL of an image, you need to extract the "src" attribute from the "img" tag within the "computer" element. Try the following code:`computer_img = computer.select("img")[0] computer_img["src"]`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want the *href*. If that's the case then:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as BS

(r := requests.get('https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deep_Blue_(chess_computer)')).raise_for_status()
soup = BS(r.text, 'lxml')

for image in soup.select('.image'):
    if href := image.get('href'):
        print(href)
```

**Output:**

```
/wiki/File:Deep_Blue.jpg
/wiki/File:Chess_Programming.svg
/wiki/File:Kasparov_Magath_1985_Hamburg-2.png
/wiki/File:One_of_Deep_Blue%27s_processors_(2586060990).jpg
/wiki/File:Chess.svg
/wiki/File:Chess.svg
```